# How to convert $argv in to a single string in the fish shell

Tags: shell, youtube-dl, fish, yt-dlp

I am writing a `fish` function to play the first result of a search term as audio using `yt-dlp` and `mpv`. The problem is that I need the search term as a single string, whereas `$argv` is an array of strings. How do I convert an array of strings to a single string in fish?

Example code:

```bash
function ytaudio
    yt-dlp -f 251 -x ytsearch:$argv -o /tmp/yt-audio.opus
    mpv /tmp/yt-audio.opus
    rm /tmp/yt-audio.opus
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to accomplish this.

1. The simplest solution is to call the function with a single argument, that is enclose the search term inside double quotes. For example

```bash
# Instead of 
$ ytaudio unity fat rat
# Use
$ ytaudio "unity fat rat"
```

The problem with this solution is that we have to type quotes to enclose the search term each time we call the function. It might not seem like much, but it is annoying if the function is called a lot of times.

2. Enclose `$argv` within quotes inside the function. Change the first line of the function to the line below.

```bash
yt-dlp -f 251 -x ytsearch:"$argv" -o /tmp/yt-audio.opus
```

3. Use `string collect` of fish. Replace the first line of the function with the lines below.

```bash
set search (echo $argv | string collect)
yt-dlp -f 251 -x ytsearch:$search -o /tmp/yt-audio.opus
```

4. Using `string join` of fish (thanks to @glennjackman). Fish has an easy and awesome way to concatenate strings. Replace the first line of the function with the two lines below.

```bash
set search (echo $argv | string join " ")
yt-dlp -f 251 -x ytsearch:$search -o /tmp/yt-audio.opus
```

`string join " "` means to join strings with a space character.

In the second, third and fourth solution, the function can be called without quotes for the search term

```bash
ytaudio unity fat rat
```

Comment: Also `string join`